# Minimal Ubuntu remastering

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, live-cd, ubuntu-minimal, minimize

I was trying to remaster an Ubuntu Mini Remix using the tool called "**Customizer**". My goal is to create a version with a GUI capable of networking too. I don't like all the Tomboy Notes, Evolution and Unity stuff that Natty come with.

http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/

http://u-customizer.sourceforge.net/

The packages I installed are just `xorg` and `gnome-desktop-environment`.

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends xorg gnome-desktop-environment
```

Well it worked quite well. I just want to ask if there are any minimum packages other that the two mentioned above? The `lubuntu-desktop` is great too but I want `gnome` more cos it has a wider community (imo).

Please don't refer me to LFS. I'm still too noob for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a truly minimal installation, I'd advise avoiding any package that has either 'desktop' or 'environment' in its name. The basic blocks of a minimal installation are: a window manager, a file browser, for example, openbox and pcmanfm, and the programs you need. Another thing to keep in mind is that `--no-install-recommends` is a tricky option. Don't be surprised if something doesn't work because of missing recommended packages. Networking doesn't require GUI tools, but if you need a network manager, try `wicd`.

For more ideas, check out the links below:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems

http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal

Comment: so those are the basic stuff.now i am enlightened :D .maybe i should try installing one by one first through virtualbox .xorg,openbox,pcmanfm. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to remaster by beginning with KDE 3.5 and the reason is, KDE 3.5 use less dependecies rather than gnome but it is okay to begin with LXDE because it is very light and fast....